# Find all combinations of each individual list element

Tags: python

Given the following list

```
myList = ['A' , 'B' , 'C, D' , 'E, F, G', 'H' , 'I']
```

How do I go about getting every possible combination for each element in the list that has more than 2 characters. I also do not want to get combinations of all of the elements together if that makes sense.

An example output using the above list would look like below:

```
myList = ['A' , 'B' , 'C, D' , 'E, F' , 'E, G' , 'F, G' , 'H' , 'I']
```

Note: I only care about finding the combinations of each element that has more than two characters.

I have attempted using a few times using itertools but that seems to want to find all possible combinations of ALL elements in the list, as opposed to combinations of the individual parts.

```
for L in range(0, len(myList)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(myList, L):
        print(subset)
```

Comment: The quotations in the list you have given seem to be inconsistent

Comment: Is there a reason that you did not include `'F, G'` in your example output or was that just an oversight?

Comment: I'll give u a starting point:

`short_list = [x for x in mylist if len(x)==1]`

`long_list = [x for x in mylist if len(x)>1]`

`split_long_list = [x.split(',') for x in long_list]`

Comment: @benvc small mistake on my end ill update accordingly

Comment: @d_kennetz this is helpful for making a new list consisting of only the 'long' elements, but still leaves the dilemma on how to make the combinations of 'each element'

Comment: split_long_list separates each long element into individual elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) on only those elements that have more than 2 letters after splitting.

```
import itertools
myList = ['A' , 'B' , 'C, D' , 'E, F, G', 'H' , 'I']

result = []

for item in myList:
    item_split = item.split(',') #split each item on , separator
    if len(item_split) <= 2:
        result.append(item)
    else: #more than 2 items after splitting. use combinations
        result.extend(",".join(pair) for pair in itertools.combinations(item_split, 2))

print(result)
#Output:
['A', 'B', 'C, D', 'E, F', 'E, G', ' F, G', 'H', 'I']
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Paritosh Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55598510/1126841), but with more parentheses :)

```
from operator import methodcaller
from itertools import chain, combinations

sep = ', '
splitter = methodcaller('split', sep)
def pairs(x):
    return combinations(x, 2 if len(x) > 1 else 1)
joiner = sep.join

result = list(map(joiner, 
                  chain.from_iterable(map(pairs, 
                                          map(splitter,
                                              my_list)))))
```

---

[DIGRESSION ALERT]

... which arguably reads a little better if you use [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations


my_list = ['A' , 'B' , 'C, D' , 'E, F, G', 'H' , 'I']

my_result = (my_list
              |> split_each
              |> pairs
              |> chain.from_iterable
              |> join_each
              |> list
             )
    where:
        split_each = map$(.split(", "))
        pairs = map$((x) -> combinations(x, 2 if len(x) > 1 else 1))
        join_each = map$(", ".join)
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know about coconut. looks a bit like magic, pretty neat!